# TestMyTriangle and MyTriangle

Tags: java, testing, boolean, area

I am posting because one of my programs is not working properly. It is a program, well, two programs, that are supposed to check if a triangle is valid and then print the area. The problem is, it never says if it is invalid even when it is. I tried messing around with the loops and it will say if it is invalid but it will not print the area properly. Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks in advanced!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTriangle 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {



         if (!valid.isValid(side1,side2,side3)) {  //Prints if the input is invalid
            System.out.print("The input is invalid");
            System.exit(0);
         }

         System.out.print("The area of the triangle is  "  //Prints the area of the triangle if valid 
            + valid.area(side1,side2,side3) + "\n");

         System.out.println("Would you like to restart? Enter y or n: ");  //Asks to restart
         restart = scan.next();
      }
      System.out.print("The program has ended!");  
   } //Ends string
} //Ends program


public class TestMyTriangle extends MyTriangle
{

   public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) 
   {
      return !(side1>side2+side3||side2>side1+side3||side3>side1+side2);
   }

   public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3)
   {
      double s;
      double area;
      s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
      area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-side1)*(s-side2)*(s-side3));
      return area;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code in Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ, I dont know what IDE youre using

Comment: I tried to run your program for input `10,20,80` and it says invalid. What is the problem?

Comment: Debug your code, put a breakpoint of the if(!valid.IsVali(...)) line and makesure that the input is indeed invalid, you should understand why it does not print if it does not

Comment: The IDE is jgrasp and the problem is I was able to input 0 for all three sides and it took it as a valid triangle and calculated.

Comment: I put the debugger breakpoint at that particular line. It seems to consider 0,0,0 valid. Almost everything else works as intended but I know that my professor is very anal and if I let that go through he will give me a failing grade. No joke.

Comment: Its your isvalid function  ..  why are you returning ! of result in the function

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your whole code looks broken and backward to me.

- You use an identifier, `valid` that is neither a declared variable nor a class, and call methods off of it as if it were a class with static methods. This code shouldn't compile.
- You've got two classes, a MyTriangle class and a TestMyTriangle, with the names implying that the 2nd class should test the first class, but your code as written seems to do the exact opposite.
- You seem to want to create a class that has state, and yet all your methods are static and there are no instance fields or methods, guaranteeing that no state-ful objects can be created.
- You're having TestMyTriangle inherit from MyTriangle for no discernable reason.

It looks to me as if you want to start over and make major changes, including

- Scrapping all this code.
- Create a MyTriangle class with three private double fields
- With a constructor that takes 3 double parameters and that sets the fields
- That has a non-static `public boolean isValid()` method that returns true of the double fields can represent a valid triangle
- That has no i/o code whatsoever, no System.out.println statements, no Scanner code.
- That has a `public double area()` method that takes no parameters, but that calculates and returns the area **based on the values held in the fields**.
- And that you have a Tester class that has a static main method
- That has all the user interaction code including use of a Scanner (if needed) and definitely `System.out.println(...)` statements.
- That creates an instance of MyTriangle and displays results from its methods.

Comment: solid answer. I don't think the OP could ask for better than this. Use this answer and update your isValid with my answer !

Comment: The problem is Eels, I am doing what I was told to. My professor is kind of a hardass and wants things done a specific way or he will give an F. There is scanner code and ln statements in MyTriangle. If I don't have it inherit and make them two programs he explicitly stated I would get a 10%. Believe me, I think it is stupid and impractical as well but he is not one to reason with. I will try to incorporate your suggestions though.

Comment: @snipem1438: please post your *actual and complete requirements*, and let's make sure that you're interpreting them correctly.

Comment: Design and implement 
two
 Java programs for progra
mming exercise 6.19, page 238. 
The first program (called 
MyTriangle
) is to implement the specified methods. The second program (called 
TestMyTriangle
) is to test the first program methods. Program 
TestMyTriangle
 is used to compute the 
area of a triangle if the input is valid. Notice that method 
isvalid()
 is used to validate the input before 
attempting to compute the area. See listings10 and 11 
(page 224) on how to write 2 programs (main program 
and test program). Design the test program main method such
 that it allowsto re-run

Comment: @snipem1438: yeah, as I figured you've got it backwards. Per the instructions, you should structure your classes as I've described above. The TestMyTriangle should have only one method, a main method and should have all println statements. The MyTriangle should have the `isValid()` method, should have the fields and constructor and other methods as I have described.

Comment: @snipem1438: and you also accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean to mark an answer since that solution didn't work. Although I wasn't expecting anyone to still reply. Either way, I did flip them. I though it was the other way around and I was reading it wrong. I still don't think it works completely correct but it does actually work now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems lies in the isValid method. Instead of doing all that you could easily make it more readable and that would solve issues by simply using the && logical operator. Sure make sure that ALL the sides are smaller than the summation of the other two. Your OR usage was the issue

```
  public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) 
   {
      return (side1<side2+side3 && side2<side1+side3 && side3<side1+side2);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is at

```
return !(side1 > side2 + side3 || side2 > side1 + side3 || side3 > side1 + side2);
```

it should be,

```
return !(side1 >= side2 + side3 || side2 >= side1 + side3 || side3 >= side1 + side2);
```

I did the following test and it works.

```
public class MyTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int side1 = 10;
        int side2 = 20;
        int side3 = 30;

        if (!isValid(side1, side2, side3)) {

            System.out.print("The input is invalid");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("The area of the triangle is  " + area(side1, side2, side3));
    }

    public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

        return !(side1 >= side2 + side3 || side2 >= side1 + side3 || side3 >= side1 + side2);
    }

    public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

        double area, tmp; 
        tmp = (side1 + side2 + side3 )/ 2;
        System.out.println("tmp is " + tmp);
        area = Math.sqrt(tmp * (tmp - side1) * (tmp - side2) * (tmp - side3));
        return area;    
    }
}
```

The other thing is, you are extending the MyTriangle with TestMyTriangle. It doesn't seem like these two classes are related other than the name. You should only extends the related parent object with a child object :)

Answer (score -2):

```
    if (!valid.isValid(side1,side2,side3)) {  //Prints if the input is invalid
                System.out.print("The input is invalid");
                System.exit(0);
             }else{
System.out.print("The area of the triangle is  "  //Prints the area of the triangle if valid 
            + valid.area(side1,side2,side3) + "\n");

         System.out.println("Would you like to restart? Enter y or n: ");  //Asks to restart
         restart = scan.next();
}

public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) 
   {
      return (side1<side2+side3 && side2<side1+side3 &&side3<side1+side2);
   }
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and mine? Plus you did an error on the last logical check side3 must be smaller than side1+side2...

Comment: The else is redundant because is the input is not valid well, it continues. In this situation, the OP was right not to put any else clause.